# How to send keys for multiple script with multiple arguments for each input box in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I have a script list nearly 100 scripts to which I need to pass argument for each scripts and these arguments are different for each script.

The way I tried passing arguments for each script individually which is consuming a lot of time and manuval intervention. Can any one suggest me an easiest way to pass my inputs to these scripts.

code i have tried the below code for passing same values for all input boxes:

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
'//*[@id="side-maincontainer-wrapper"]/div/div/div[2]/earms-suitehome/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiNEC.png)/earms-categorydetails/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/clr-datagrid/clr-dg-action-bar/button[3]').click()
num_scripts=54
for i in range(0, (num_scripts - 1)):
#time.sleep(20)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
'//*[@id="side-maincontainer-wrapper"]/div/div/div[2]/earms-requestrunhome/earms-testbedselection/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiNEC.png)/div/form/div/div/div/div/div/div/clr-datagrid/div/div/div/clr-dg-table-wrapper/div[2]/clr-dg-row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiNEC.png)/div/clr-dg-cell[3]/input//div').send_keys(
"--crft --crft-devices pireg-nyquist1-1 pireg-nyquist1-2 --btrace-devices uut --btrace --configuration /auto/arf1/vramiyen/pyats_crft/SELinux_plugin/config.yaml --selinux --selinux-devices uut --template /auto/bgl-xeinfra/pmotukan/template.input --platform /auto/arf1/vramiyen/pyats_crft/SELinux_plugin/platform.py")

[image snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiNEC.png)

attached the picture below ,so i need to pass my args in that cmd line input box,and the arguments for each box are different

Comment: Can you share your code? How those scripts look like? How and where you store arguments?

Comment: added my code and required image snippets in my question

Answer (score 0):

I have used this module before for parsing arguments:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

The argparse module makes it easy to write user-friendly command-line interfaces. The program defines what arguments it requires, and argparse will figure out how to parse those out of sys.argv. The argparse module also automatically generates help and usage messages and issues errors when users give the program invalid arguments.

This is just a general solution as the question currently contains no code.

Comment: Attached my request image snippet above